# D3 v4 graph not updating bars - but appending new axis data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have seen this type of question asked a lot but no answers i found solved it for me.

I created a fiddle here of a stripped down simplified version of my code

https://jsfiddle.net/00m2cv84/4/

here is a snippet of the ganttish object - best to check out the fiddle though for context

```
const ganttish = function (data) {
  this.dataSet = data
  this.fullWidth = +document.getElementById('chart').clientWidth
  this.fullHeight = 700
  this.pad = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }
  this.h = this.fullHeight - this.pad.top - this.pad.bottom
  this.w = this.fullWidth - this.pad.left - this.pad.right
  this.svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', this.fullWidth)
    .attr('height', this.fullHeight)
}

ganttish.prototype = {
  redraw (newDataSet) { 
    this.dataSet = newDataSet // this should overwrite the old data
    this.draw()
  },
  draw () {
    let y = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.1)
    .range([0, this.h])
    y.domain(this.dataSet.map(d => d.idea_id))

    let x = d3.scaleTime().range([this.pad.left, this.w + this.pad.left])
    x.domain([
      d3.min(this.dataSet, d => new Date(Date.parse(d.start_date))),
      d3.max(this.dataSet, d => new Date(Date.parse(d.end_date)))
    ])

    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-(this.h), 0, 0)
    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(-(this.w), 0, 0)

    let xA = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.h + ')')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .call(xAxis)

    let yA = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.pad.left + ', 0)')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .call(yAxis)

    let timeBlocks = this.svg.selectAll('.timeBlock')
      .data(this.dataSet)

    let tbGroup = timeBlocks
      .enter()
      .append('g')

    tbGroup
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'timeBlock')
      .attr('rx', 5)
      .attr('ry', 5)
      .attr('x', d => x(new Date(Date.parse(d.start_date))))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.idea_id))
      .attr('width', d => parseInt(x(new Date(Date.parse(d.end_date))) - x(new Date(Date.parse(d.start_date)))))
      .attr('height', d => y.bandwidth())
      .style('fill', (d) => {
        return d.color ? d.color : 'rgba(123, 173, 252, 0.7)'
      })
      .style('stroke', 'black')
      .style('stroke-width', 1)

    tbGroup
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'timeBlockText')
      .attr('x', d => x(new Date(Date.parse(d.start_date))) + 10)
      .attr('y', d => y(d.idea_id) + (y.bandwidth() / 2))
      .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
      .attr('font-size', '1em')
      .attr('color', 'black')
      .text(d => d.name)

    /**
      I have literally tried exit().remove() on pretty much everything i could think of :(
      this.svg.exit().remove()
      timeBlocks.exit().remove()
      this.svg.selectAll('.timeBlock').exit().remove()
      this.svg.selectAll('.timeBlockText').exit().remove()
      this.svg.select('.x').exit().remove()
      this.svg.select('.y').exit().remove()
    */
  }
```

Sidenote:
I have a Vue js application and i'm implementing a Gantt(ish) style horizontal bar chart.  In the fiddle i have simulated the Vue part by creating an Object which then you call the redraw method on it, this pattern simulates a watcher in the component updating the dataset when the parent data changes.  The issue i face is the same.

issue:
When i change the data to the chart it does not update my chart rects or text.  It does however append the new axis' on top of the old ones.

i understand that i should be calling .exit().remove() on anything .enter() 'd when finished in order to clear them for the next data push, but everywhere i try this it fails.  I can get it to work by creating a fresh svg on every draw, but i understand i won't be able to do any transitions - and it seems a very bad approach :)

What is twisting my noodle is that if i push extra data to the new data object, it appends it fine, once - then does not do it again.  It seems once element X in the data array has been added it will not update again.

https://jsfiddle.net/00m2cv84/5/

I know that the this.dataSet is updating, it just does not seem to be accepted by D3

Any help would be greatly appreciated for a D3 noob :)

Comment: Thanks @Ian, i'm not sure what this should achieve, i tried it but did not know what to expect to see, could you elaborate?  I perhaps I put in the wrong place :)

Comment: in fact going back and reading ignore that advice - You're not actually handling the update properly. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that you're not handling your data join properly. I'd highly recommend reading some of Mike Bostock's examples probably starting with [Three Little Circles](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/). To summarize though:

D3 joins created by calling `.data()` contain 3 selections:

- Enter (DOM elements that need to be created as they exist in the data but don't yet exist in the DOM)
- Exit (DOM elements that need to be removed, as they're not longer represented in the data)
- Update (DOM elements that already exist and still exist in the data)

Within your code you're handling the `enter()` selection with this bit of code:

```
let tbGroup = timeBlocks
  .enter()
  .append('g')
```

The problem is you're not handling any of the other selections. The way I'd go about doing this is:

```
let join = this.svg.selectAll('.timeBlock').data(this.dataSet);

// Get rid of any old data
join.exit().remove();

// Create the container groups. Note that merge takes the "new" selection
// and merges it with the "update" selection. We'll see why in a minute
const newGroups = join.enter()
                      .append('g')
                       .merge(join);

// Create all the new DOM elements that we need
newGroups.append("rect").attr("class", "timeBlock");
newGroups.append('text').attr('class', 'timeBlockText');

// We need to set values for all the "new" items, but we also want to
// reflect any changes that have happened in the data. Because we used
// `merge()` previously, we can access all the "new" and "update" items
// and set their values together.
join.select(".timeBlock")
    .attr('rx', 5)
    .attr('ry', 5)
    .attr('x', d => x(new Date(Date.parse(d.start_date))))
    .attr('y', d => y(d.idea_id))
    ...

join.select(".timeBlockText")
    .attr('x', d => x(new Date(Date.parse(d.start_date))) + 10)
    .attr('y', d => y(d.idea_id) + (y.bandwidth() / 2))
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('font-size', '1em')
    .attr('color', 'black')
    .text(d => d.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ian.  I had a quick look at this and tried to get something to work.  No luck so far, i'm going to have a look at it later today.  Thanks again.

Comment: I was unsure as to what "timeBlocks" variable in your example was meant to be now, i assumed that was a typo as "timeblocks" was essentially the "join" variable and assuming i am not joining it to itself. Or am i? :) Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Rossidge the `timeBlocks` was from your original code. I renamed it to `join` in my example as I believed it provided better clarity. Yeah I've just spotted the typo where `newGroups` is defined which I'll update, but indeed you do need to merge with yourself. That function merges just the `enter` part, with the `update` part, allowing you to update all your attributes with a single copy of the code. Otherwise you end up updating `rx` for example within the enter, and duplicating that for the update elements.

Comment: i have not managed to get the example to work yet, but i understand the issue and your answer points that out @Ian.  Going to mark as solved.  Thanks for your time